# Comparing variable to empty jquery object in if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the jQuery accordion API, it says "If the accordion is collapsing, ui.newHeader and ui.newPanel will be empty jQuery objects."

How can I check if ui.newheader is an empty jQuery object? I've tried it like this:

```
if ($(ui.newHeader) == null)
{
    ...
}
```

,like this:

```
if (ui.newHeader == null)
{
    ...
}
```

and this:

```
if ($(ui.newHeader) == "")
{
    ...
}
```

So basically, this is a question about jquery/javascript syntax :) Thanks

Comment: It's not really a syntax question - all three of the things you tried are valid JavaScript syntax, they just don't do what you want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is to know if there is 0 element in the set. Do it like this :

```
if ($(ui.newHeader).length==0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!$(ui.newHeader).length)
```

or

```
if (!$(ui.newHeader)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery object is array like collection. So, it is empty means, it's `length` property is `0`.

```
if(!$(ui.newHeader).length) {...}
```